# The scroll detection doesn't work after calling a new page Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app using phonegap , everything work fine except the scroll detection! it works fine until I move to another page using the jQueryMobile data transition , after that it doesn't work at all though everything else work just fine!

here's the code that I use for the scroll detection

```
// to check if I reached the bottom of the slide
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
 // my code goes here
}
// to check if I'm at the top of the slide
if(document.body.scrollTop == 0 ) {
 // my code goes here
}
```

Comment: Its hard to tell with minimal code, my guess would be a javascript error or some object does not exist on the page. Use your browser console and log various events..

Comment: I don't receive any comments , if you want to see the project check the link I added

Comment: You still need to add a little more code to your post, having a link to a site that is not a fiddle does not help always. I could spend an hour reading over your code or just wait til you post a fiddle reproducing the error. Looking at your page, it does not produce any javascript errors when you change pages. But your pages are dynamic, not static.. So my first guess would be that when you change pages.. your losing reference to the div/container or something along those lines

Comment: When you load a new page/content.. Try re-running that code for a start.. See if it works in that case at least.

Comment: @Mayhem the function I wrote name is Scrollit() ... anyway you got a point and I tried the "pagecreate" & "pageshow" and the rest of the events from the jQuery Mobile and nothing worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution , all I did was following this method to detect the scrolling and it works just fine!

https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/infinite-scrolling/

Special thanks for the jQMtricks admin **Omar** for this great way of detecting

Answer (score 0):

try to change your `==` signs to:

```
// to check if I reached the bottom of the slide
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
    // my code goes here
}
// to check if I'm at the top of the slide
if(document.body.scrollTop <= 0 ) {
    // my code goes here
}
```

Sometimes, after some calculations, their values may be inferior or greater causing a bug, so it's wise to use `<=` and `>=` where needed.
Not sure if will help though.